# Jenkins parameterized build and Subversion post-commit hook

Tags: svn, jenkins, post-commit-hook

I have a parameterized job so user can select the specific revision to build. The job’s Repository URL includes the revision build param like this:

```
           http://svn/app/trunk/@${revision}
```

This works fine when running the build manually. But the notifyCommit from my post-commit hook doesn’t find the job (error is “No subversion consumers…”). I know it is because of "@${revision}" in the URL. If I remove that part, the job is triggered by a Subversion commit with no problems.

Is there any way we can use the **same** job for both purposes: (1) manual build for specific revision and (2) auto build by post-commit hook?

We’re using Jenkins 2.54, Java 1.8_121 and Subversion Plugin version 2.7.2.